# Node.js, 'X' is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter

I've been pulling my hair out with this one, trying to get my latest tweets as an array with https://github.com/noffle/latest-tweets npm module. however, no matter what way i seem to order it, i get some form of error. mainly posts is not defined
or tweets is not defined.

```js
var express = require('express');
var latestTweets = require('latest-tweets')
var Post = require('../models/blog');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
 Post.getPosts((err, posts) => {
  if(err){
   throw err;
  }
 });
 latestTweets('my_twitter_id', function (err, tweets) {
   console.log(tweets)
 })
    res.render('index', {tweets : tweets, posts : posts});

});
```

I also tried to export the latestTweets function into a helper class which lead to more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take care of the **scope** of the variable while writing code. The `posts` and `tweets` variables are accessible only inside the callback functions in which they are passed as arguments, but you are accessing them outside their scope. Clearly, since the argument `tweets` is passed inside the callback of `latestTweets`, the variable `tweets` has a local scope limited to the callback. So, when the program reaches `res.render`, it tries to evaluate `tweets` and `posts`, and fails to identify them, and returns `not defined`. 
**Example**

```
function myFunc(){
    var x = 0;
}
console.log(x);
```

The above function will return the same error `x is not defined`, since the outer code doesn't know what `x` is. It is local to the function `myFunc`, and  is only accessible inside it. To make it accessible, you will have to make it global, i.e., declare `var x = 0` in the main code. 
In your code, the best you can do is declare two variables inside the `router.get` function's callback (i.e., global to the callback) and assign them to `posts` and `tweets` in their respective callbacks.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var tweets, posts;
Post.getPosts((err, posts) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    posts = posts;
});
latestTweets('my_twitter_id', function (err, tweets) {
console.log(tweets)
tweets = tweets;
})
res.render('index', {tweets : tweets, posts : posts});

});
```

Using [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session) is a better option than declaring variables while writing backend, because of a lot of reasons, which would be off-topic to explain here.
**Also**, avoid using nested callbacks. In this case, `res.render` might be called before the global variables `tweets` and `posts` are assigned a value, which will again throw an error signifying `tweets` and `posts` are `undefined`. In such cases, use Javascript's [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is the language's own feature to handle such requests.

Answer (score 1):

Both posts and tweets are variables from the callbacks.
You can't use them outside the callback.

Quick fix:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Post.getPosts((err, posts) => {
        if(err){ throw err; }

        latestTweets('my_twitter_id', function (err_, tweets) {
            if(err_){ throw err_; }
            console.log(tweets);

            res.render('index', {tweets : tweets, posts : posts});
        });
    });
});
```

Now, if you're looking for a prettier solution you can take a look at async module. [async repo](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md)

Comment: Thanks, i ran your fix above, minus the typos :P however it, simply returns an empty array. ive had success parssing the array to the console log with other attempts, but never to my route. i will in time look at the link you sugested

Comment: stupidly i didnt change the username to my correct twitter id. That caused the empty array.